# jquery change image in click and backwards

Tags: jquery, image, attr

i am sorry for this simple thing, but the image change doesn't work with this. i've tried a lot of options but maybe i can not see the problem.

```
 $('#accordion li.first').click(function() {
                    if ($(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop.png')) {
                        $(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop90.png');
                    }
                    if ($(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop90.png')) {
                        $(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop.png');
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: The form of `$.attr()` you are using is setting the 'src' attribute, not testing if it is equal to the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#accordion li.first').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), $img = $this.children('img'), src = $img.attr('src');

    switch (src) {
        case 'img/drop.png':
            $img.attr('src', 'img/drop90.png');
        break;

        case 'img/drop90.png':
            $img.attr('src', 'img/drop.png');
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
if ($(this).children('img').attr('src')=='img/drop.png') {
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop.png')) {
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something differently then follow the steps:-

1. Add class `drop` & `drop90` for the image
2. On `drop` & `drop90` CSS class, apply 
      `background-image: url(img/drop.png);` and `background-image: url(img/drop90.png);`
3. Use the mentioned Jquery and sample CSS to toggle the two classes using the function `toggleClass()`

### JQuery:

```
$('#accordion li.first').click(function() {
    $(this).children('img').toggleClass("drop drop90");
});​
```

### CSS:

```
.​drop​ {
    background-image: url(img/drop.png); 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 200px;
}
.drop90 {
    background-image: url(img/drop90.png); 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 200px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

if ($(this).find('img').attr('src') === 'img/drop.png')  will always evaluate to **true..**
because you are assigning the value to it and not comparing

Try this instead

```
 $('#accordion li.first').click(function() {
       if ($(this).children('img').attr('src') === 'img/drop.png') {
          $(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop90.png');
        }
        if ($(this).children('img').attr('src') === 'img/drop90.png') {
               $(this).children('img').attr('src','img/drop.png');
        }
 });
```